# LinkButton not working due to validation control field

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

In my .aspx page which derives from a master page I have a contact form which uses some validation, such as the RequiredFieldValidator and RegularExpressValidator.

At top of my page I have a link bar and whenver I am at contact.aspx I can't navigate to the other pages as if that I need to fill in the necessary data so that it satisfies the validator. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `CausesValidation` property of the controls in your link bar (I'm assuming they're LinkButtons) to `False`.

Comment: I had the same problem it worked ,by this but can you please explain why it was not working before and working now ,so i have some idea.Please.